# Meaning of the tilde symbol in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, tilde

I came across this code

```
fm <- y ~ x
mods <- setNames(as.list(1:4), paste0("lm", 1:4))
# loop over the four datasets in the quartet
for(i in 1:4) {
  fm[2:3] <- lapply(paste0(c("y","x"), i), as.name)
  mods[[i]] <- lmi <- lm(fm, data=anscombe)
```

I guessed the `~` in this case referring to the *linear relationship* between `y` and `x`, but what is its "overall" meaning?

Also, what exactly is the variable `fm` and what does the index `[2:3]` (as in `fm[2:3]`) refer to? Can someone please explain?

Comment: `help("formula")` ....

Comment: If you look at `as.character(fm)`, you'll see `c("~", "y", "x")`, which means that `fm[2:3] <- ...` is doing simple index replacement: it replaces `"y"` and `"x"` with the results of the RHS (while keeping it as a formula, that is). This should be further clear when looking at `fm` both before and after that sub-assignment.

Comment: Help pages also accessible with `?tilde`, `?"~"`, etc.

Comment: Thanks @r2evans for the tips. That's most helpful for people like me. I didn't know that it's possible to look "inside" the variable `fm`.